# Spacing between certain rows/columns with CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table

I don't have a lot of experience with css styling tables (basic understanding, but that's it).

I need to obtain something similar to this:

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.space {
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    border: none
}
```

```html
<table>
      <tr>
        <td id="1_1">1_1</td>
        <td class="space"></td>
        <td id="1_2">1_2</td>
        <td id="1_3">1_3</td>
        <td id="1_4">1_4</td>
        <td id="1_5">1_5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="space"></td>
        <td class="space"></td>
        <td class="space"></td>
        <td class="space"></td>
        <td class="space"></td>
        <td class="space"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="2_1">2_1</td>
        <td class="space"></td>
        <td id="2_2">2_2</td>
        <td id="2_3">2_3</td>
        <td id="2_4">2_4</td>
        <td id="2_5">2_5</td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/7Lhwb0f3/

I need to do it without adding the empty `tr` and the empty `td`s. The table I have to style is automatically generated and thus I cannot modify it, and the only elements it has are those that you can visually see in the example.

I tried searching for alternatives but all I found was styling that affected *all the inner spacing*, not the ones I specifically need. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not sure if that is actually possible. You can not work with margins here, and any padding inside the the cells will also move the border ... If you could perhaps apply the borders to the content inside the table cells, it might work that way; but other than that, I don’t think there is an actual solution.

Comment: you can fake some borders with box-shadow and draw one transparent the size of the gap to fake it https://jsfiddle.net/7Lhwb0f3/1/

Answer (score 0):

this can be accomplished with some css, consider the following HTML.

HTML

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: block;
}

td:first-child {
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="1_1">1_1</td>
        <td id="1_2">1_2</td>
        <td id="1_3">1_3</td>
        <td id="1_4">1_4</td>
        <td id="1_5">1_5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="2_1">2_1</td>
        <td id="2_2">2_2</td>
        <td id="2_3">2_3</td>
        <td id="2_4">2_4</td>
        <td id="2_5">2_5</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I hope this what what you where looking for.

Comment: block, inline-block and float unfortunately resets the table-layout and columns won't go through rows as supposed too :(

Comment: you need to test live with content of different size : https://jsfiddle.net/7Lhwb0f3/3/ ;) to see layout breaking